# Does gcc have a extension overload for std::vector::emplace_back?

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, move, emplace

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), `std::vector::emplace_back` has only one signature, which is:

```cpp
template< class... Args >
reference emplace_back( Args&&... args );
```

And in the description, it says `emplace_back` is supposed to forward each of its arguments to the constructor of the type in the `vector`. However, when I tested the following code using gcc 12.2, it successfully compiles:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    Foo foo(1, 2);
    foos.push_back(std::move(foo));
    foos.emplace_back(foo); // weird
}
```

(See on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9jEbMdfbr))

I expected the line `foos.emplace_back(foo);` to fail the compilation. It seems as if `emplace_back` has this overload:

```cpp
template< class T >
reference emplace_back( T& arg );
```

which isn't mentioned in the documentation. Am I missing something or is this just a compiler extension?

Comment: `T&&` as forwarding reference can deduced to `T&`

Comment: A **template** `T&&` parameter is a *forwarding reference*, and it is **not** quite the same as a non-template `Foo&&` parameter *rvalue reference* (a "moving" reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> foos.emplace_back(foo); // weird
> ```

That's weird indeed! You ask to `emplace_back`, meaning you're calling the constructor, and you're passing `foo` to the constructor. Hence, you're calling the copy constructor. `push_back` would have done the same!

That's an implicitly defined default copy constructor, see [cppreference on Copy Constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-declared_copy_constructor):

> If no user-defined copy constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a copy constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class.

You didn't define a copy constructor, so the compiler did that for you, as dictated by C++. You can avoid that and make your compilation fail:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y)
    {}
    
    //! Explicitly deleted default copy constructor.
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
};
```

> ```
> foos.push_back(std::move(foo));
> ```

He're you're calling the move constructor. Note that you're using `foo` after moving from it, that's more or less illegal (you throwing `std::move` at `foo` means that `foo` is no longer supposed to hold any resources.)

Should you really happen to just want to delete the move constructor, same syntax, basically: `Foo(Foo&&) = delete;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
template< class... Args >
reference emplace_back( Args&&... args );
```

can deduced to something like (with `Args = Foo&`)

```
reference emplace_back( Foo& && args[0] );
```

which collapse to

```
reference emplace_back( Foo& args[0] );
```